# How to change ArrayList Models into JSON

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, gson

I have two models Category and SubCategory.
Category has List which is one to many relationship and when I fetch data from DB, I got one category has many subcateogry. My purpose is to create above relationship data into JSON format type to show on browser. For example, fetching data like, List = categoryService.getAllList(); return a List of Category in which also include specific list of subcategory.

Category.java

```
@Entity
public class Category implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5774598582410455895L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int categoryId;

    @NotEmpty(message = "The category name must not be empty")
    @Size(min = 3, max = 20, message = "Minimum 3 to 20 characters allowed")
    private String categoryName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<SubCategory> subCategory;
//getter setter
```

SubCategory.java

```
@Entity
public class SubCategory implements Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7750738516036520962L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer subCategoryId;

    @NotEmpty(message = "The subcategory name must not be empty")
    @Size(min = 3, max = 20, message = "Minimum 3 to 20 characters allowed")
    private String subCategoryName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="categoryId")
    private Category category;
//getter setter
```

ControllerSample.java

```
@RequestMapping(value="/prodList.json")
    public @ResponseBody String sectionList(ModelMap modelMap) throws JsonProcessingException{
          Gson gson = new Gson();
          String jsondata = gson.toJson(categoryService.getAllCategroy());
          System.out.println("jsondata = " + jsondata);

    return jsondata;
    }
```

ErrorLog

```
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:113)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:240)
at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:950)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:113)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:240)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
```

The error might be due to Gson went in Infinity loop and trying to convert Category List upon inside SubCategory List.

Please help me to overcome this.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use @Expose Annotation. Like this:

Category.java

```
@Entity
public class Category implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5774598582410455895L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Expose
    private int categoryId;

    @NotEmpty(message = "The category name must not be empty")
    @Size(min = 3, max = 20, message = "Minimum 3 to 20 characters allowed")
    @Expose
    private String categoryName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Expose
    private List<SubCategory> subCategory;
```

SubCategory.java

```
@Entity
public class SubCategory implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7750738516036520962L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Expose
    private Integer subCategoryId;

    @NotEmpty(message = "The subcategory name must not be empty")
    @Size(min = 3, max = 20, message = "Minimum 3 to 20 characters allowed")
    @Expose
    private String subCategoryName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="categoryId")
    private Category category;
```

And you can use Gson like this:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
String jsondata = gson.toJson(categoryService.getAllCategroy());
System.out.println("jsondata = " + jsondata);
```

Comment: thank you for your support, this really works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring Heteos to link the other entity by relation.

For more details [click here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-hateoas/)